# Why Main Thread is executes first before Child Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

**By calling t.start()...logically it calls run method and will display Child Thread.... But why Main Thread is executing first before Child Thread?**

```
class Mythread extends Thread
    {
    public void run()
    {
    for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("child thread........");
    }
    }
    }

    public class ThreadDemo
    {
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
    Mythread t=new Mythread();

    t.start();

    for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("main thread........");
    }
    } 
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your question as a text, not a screenshot.

Comment: I takes quite a bit of time to create and start up a Thread, so unless you block for the Thread to complete `join` then the `Main` will finish first

Answer (score 1):

Well, why shouldn't it?

The main thread is already running, it is possible the scheduler would prefer to let it keep running. It's up to the OS scheduler to decide which thread runs when for how long.

There is no rule that a thread should stop running as soon as it spawns a new thread. Since it may take a while to create the new thread, the starting thread would grind to  a halt.  Instead the scheduler is allowed to do what it thinks is best.